# Add target _blank on ckeditor5

Tags: 9, wysiwyg

I'm using the experimental ckeditor5 editor on my drupal 9 project.
I have the need to allow the editor to choose whether to open a link in a new tab (target: _blank) or in the same tab.

Usually there where possibilities on the link field in the editor to specify this settings, but I found out here https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3247683 that somehow on D9 it has been removed.

Still, I cannot understand how to allow the editor to specify the target on a link, no option is showing up neither I know where I could allow these.

Comment: Looks like this is currently in progress in contrib: https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link/issues/3232052

Comment: Yes, but right now it seems the only way is by going back to ckeditor 4. Or maybe developing some sort of filter, but I couldn't find a proper guide. Amd it would still be too much to achieve a simple target in a link...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Editor Advanced Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/editor_advanced_link) module to add the ability to open links in a new window. (It would be nice for this to be in Core, but at least there's a contrib solution!)

The module enables these settings in the text format filters:
ARIA label ()
Title ()
CSS classes ()
ID ()
Open in new window ()
Link relationship ()